# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que un elemento se coloque debajo de otro en tamaño pequeño?

Tags: html, bootstrap

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-9 " style="flex-grow: 1;">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row px-3 mb-3 align-items-center justify-content-around bg-white rounded border shadow-sm" style="min-height: 70px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="assignProfileModal()" >Asignar Perfil </button>
    <!-- <button class="base-button" (click)="assignProfileModal()"> Asignar Perfil </button> -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="blockUserModal()"> {{ userCardData?.idStatus == '119' ? "Desbloquear usuario" : "Bloquear usuario" }} </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="openSelectBank()"> Descargar Perfil</button>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center m-0 p-0 selectOption">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-sm-12">
        <mat-label>Opciones de vistas</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="currentView">
            <mat-option [value]="option.value" *ngFor="let option of listOfInfoOption">
                {{ option.text }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podrías por favor ir a [edit] y explicar **dentro** de la pregunta, junto al código, cuál es el problema con ese fragmento de código y qué esperas que pase?